# JQUERY Battery Meter

Tags: javascript, jquery, raspberry-pi

I'm looking for a simple jquery or javascript based Battery meter that will simply take in a var of 1-100 and display it. Ultimately this will be hooked into a Raspberry Pi to monitor the battery life on it.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/ with css to make it look like a battery?

Comment: This should do it. http://jsfiddle.net/ffWYb/1/

Comment: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, **describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.**"*

Comment: or even *"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. **Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.** See also: Stack Overflow question checklist"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [Bootstrap Progress Bar](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#progress) would work very well here.

```
<div class="progress" id="battery">
  <!-- initial battery life -->
  <div class="bar" style="width: 60%;"></div>
</div>
```

Script

```
var battery = // define battery in your script
battery.on("update", function() {
  $("#battery .bar").css("width", battery.life + "%");
});
```